# Performance issue with pipeline with sort on dynamic $project

Tags: mongodb, performance, sorting, projection, ranking

I have performance issue on this given aggregation:

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { 
    // reduce to users that have first or second level users in their friends list
    "$match:": {"friendOf": {"$in": [ObjectId("59b1b8025c69f2ae693f36d7"), ObjectId("59b1b8025c69f2ae693f36d8"), ObjectId("59b309835c69f24829057eb5"), ObjectId("59b458aa5c69f272513907e5")}}
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "ranking": {
        "$sum": [
          {
            "$cond": {
              "if": { // first level friends
                "$setIsSubset": ["$friendOf", [ObjectId("59b1b8025c69f2ae693f36d7"), ObjectId("59b1b8025c69f2ae693f36d8")]]
              },
              "then": 2, // weight: 2
              "else": 0
            }
          },
          { 
            "$cond": {
              "if": { // second level friends
                "$setIsSubset": ["$friendOf": [ObjectId("59b309835c69f24829057eb5"), ObjectId("59b458aa5c69f272513907e5")]]
              },
              "then": 1, // weight: 1
              "else": 0
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {"ranking": 1}
  },
  {
    "$limit": 20
  }
]);
```

With a user collection, where 'friendOf' property take a list of ObjectId() corresponding on if the user have an other user as friend.

The goal of the query is to sort user by their proximity with first then second list of users.

The problem I have is that I use "ranking" key as sort field.

Because of it's a query dependent projection, I can't precompute and store this field to benefit of the Mongo Index.

Because of the purpose of the query is ranking, I can't "$limit" the scope before the $sort.

So, I'm looking for a better approach to handle my problematic.

Note: I use MongoDB 3.4.10 version

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

In reality do you only have 2 levels of friends? 1 point and 2 points? and will you ever want to see the 21-40 results? If not then you could simply do two queries to MongoDB and with a $group on `_id` and `$sum:1` to get a total count of friends, do the $sort and $limit 20 steps inside the AF and then merge the 2 and resort inside your app to apply the 2 points scoring.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer :).

> In reality do you only have 2 levels of friends?
Nop, it's just an illustration of the problematic

> 1 point and 2 points?
The same, it's just to illustrate that there is some weight/dynamic processing to rank the result

To reduce the problem: how to improve performance when result is sorted by a dynamic projection